# Installing cvblobslib on BeagleBone Black (Linux Angstrom)

Tags: linux, opencv, beagleboneblack, cvblobslib

I am brand new to BeagleBone Black and, most of all, using a Linux distro from the terminal only.  I am in the process of building a robot where it will be necessary to detect areas of a certain color from the webcam attached to the BBB.  The BBB I am using has Linux Angstrom installed by default, which includes v4l and OpenCV.  It does not include the cvblobslib, a "blob-detectng" library for OpenCV, however.  Could somebody give me a walkthrough of how to install this library onto my BBB via the ssh terminal?